# plotting survival object: legend formatting

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

Here is my example

```
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
plot(fit, col=c("orange","purple"), lty=c(1:2), lwd=3, # base with some customization
     conf.int = TRUE, xmax = 2000)
# add a legend
legend(100, .2, c("Ovarian Cancer", "Breast Cancer"), 
       lty = c(1:2), col=c("orange","purple"))
```

Here is how plot look like:
[image: survival plot with legend]

I also tried

```
legend('bottomleft', c("Ovarian Cancer", "Breast Cancer"), 
       lty = c(1:2), col=c("orange","purple"))
```

Legend only look marginally better

Does anybody know how to fix the legend?

**Update** I am on Win 7 and R is 3.3.3

Comment: I am running your code on a Window7 PC with R 3.3.3. The legend is pretty, not like yours.

Comment: Same here except with R 3.3.2. Seeing a standard legend.

Comment: Could you also post the plot that you get when using `legend("topright"` ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri , Still looks horrible. I also tried it in native R editior instead of R studio.